# An integral with limits being a funtion of a parameter.

Tags: calculus

Could anyone please explain / derive this formula for me? I encountered it in a probability textbook but can't understand it:

Suppose we have an integral in the following form:
$$
R(\alpha) = \int_{a(\alpha)}^{b(\alpha)} r(\alpha , x)dx
$$
Then,
$$
\frac{dR(\alpha)}{d\alpha} = -r(\alpha , a(\alpha)) \frac{da(\alpha)}{d\alpha} + r(\alpha , b(\alpha)) \frac{db(\alpha)}{\alpha} + \int_{a(\alpha)}^{b(\alpha)} \frac{\partial r(\alpha, x)}{\partial \alpha} dx
$$

Comment: Reference: [Differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

Comment: Very clear proof, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_Statement).

Comment: And a very handy tool!